# finding index of element sitewide

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have been trying to find out how to do a sitewide search for an elements index of a certain class. Doesn't have to sitewide, but i has to be usuable for an ancestor div.

My markup is the following:

```
<div class="custom-woo-gallery">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery-item"></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery-item"></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery-item"></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery-item"></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery-item"></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"></div>
        <div class="gallery-item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically a `.gallery-item` element is clicked and i need to find out how many `.gallery-item` elements preceeds it in the common ancestor `.custom-woo-gallery`.

I have the following code, which is functional. But I'm guessing theres more simple way to do this. I just can't seem to find anything on google other than `index()` and `eq()` which only seems to work inside the same parent div.

```
function getPrev(){
    var count = 0;
    $(clicked).parent().prevUntil().each(function(){
        count = count + $(this).children().length;
    })
    var self = $(clicked).prevUntil().length;
    return count + self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. If you have only one `custom-woo-gallery`, you can get the index of the current clicked `gallery-item`'s index via [**jQuery#index**](https://api.jquery.com/index/). And you can find how many how many `.gallery-item` elements precedes it.

Actually the `index` of the clicked div is the number of his previous `.gallery-item`s.

```js
const galleryItems = $('.gallery-item');

$('.gallery-item').on('click', function(){
  console.log(galleryItems.index($(this)));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-woo-gallery">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery-item">1</div>
        <div class="gallery-item">2</div>
        <div class="gallery-item">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery-item">4</div>
        <div class="gallery-item">5</div>
        <div class="gallery-item">6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery-item">7</div>
        <div class="gallery-item">8</div>
        <div class="gallery-item">9</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery-item">10</div>
        <div class="gallery-item">11</div>
        <div class="gallery-item">12</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="gallery-item">13</div>
        <div class="gallery-item">14</div>
        <div class="gallery-item">15</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed!
Wasn't aware index worked that way.